Reverse order of lines in text file using a batch
I successfully reversed the order of lines in a text file using the below batch, however Original.txt has spaces (in between each line there is 1 CRLF) and Reversed.txt removes all CRLF (Carriage Return/Line Feed).
Is there a way to keep the CRLFs in Reversed.txt?
Thanks for any creative support :)
@echo off
ren *.txt Original.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem/> Reversed.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (Original.txt) do (
   (
   echo(%%a
   type Reversed.txt
   ) > temp.txt
   move /Y temp.txt Reversed.txt > NUL
)


A standard For /F, like you have shown, will omit all 'empty' lines. The standard way of working around that is to use findstr.exe or find.exe with their /N option. This includes the line numbers in their output, which you can then process further to remove the numbering, in your Do section. For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "Original.txt"') Do ... or For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /N /V "" 0^<"Original.txt"') Do .... There should be plenty of examples throughout this site showing how this may be achieved.

Here's how I'd suggest it is done, which is an expansion of the method I mentioned in the comments. It is similar to the answer already submitted, but lines beginning with ] will not be problematic.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "*.txt" ? /LQ | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^1\>" 1>NUL || Exit /B
For %%G In ("*.txt") Do Set "orig=%%G"
Ren "%orig%" "Original.txt"
CD.>"Reversed.txt"
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /N /V "" 0^<"Original.txt"') Do (Set "Line=%%G"
    (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo(!Line:*]=!
        Endlocal
        Type "Reversed.txt") 1>"temp.txt"
    Move /Y "temp.txt" "Reversed.txt" 1>NUL)
Ren "Original.txt" "%orig%"

I took the liberty of adding some lines to have the original text file returned to its name after reversing it. I also added some code to exit the script if there is more than one file matching *.txt glob.

AWESOME this does EXACTLY what I needed. You rock, man!

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

rem/> u:\Reversed.txt
for /F "tokens=1*delims=]" %%b in ('FIND "" /v /n ^<q79258953.txt') do (
   (
   echo/%%c
   type u:\Reversed.txt
   ) > u:\temp.txt
   move /Y u:\temp.txt u:\Reversed.txt > NUL
)

TYPE u:\Reversed.txt
GOTO :EOF

For the reasons mentioned in the comments.
I used a file named q79258953.txt on my RAMDRIVE containing some dummy data for my testing.
This obviously will not work for input file lines beginning ].
